# ggplot2 second Y axis breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

**Hello, having below data, I would like to modify second Y axis (for inflation - right side) using this way to start with value 0.994 and finish with 1.04, left y axis with no changes - see my code below**

```
Year <- 2016:2020

inflation_value <- c(0.994,1.020, 1.016, 1.023, 1.034)

net_benefit <- numeric(5)

net_benefit[1] <- 500


for (i in 2:5){
  net_benefit[i] <-  net_benefit[i-1]-(net_benefit[i-1]*(inflation_value[i]-1))
}

df <- data.frame(Year, inflation_value, net_benefit)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Year))+
  geom_col(aes(y = net_benefit), fill = "#69b3a2")+
  geom_line(aes(y = inflation_value*400), col = rgb(0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1), size = 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Net benefit",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~./400, name = "Inflation"))+
  theme_ipsum()
```

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZlrn.png)

Comment: Actually,  breaks has impact only on right y axis label, inflation lineplot didnt change

Comment: Does this produce your expected output ? : `df %>% ggplot(aes(x=Year))+
geom_col(aes(y = net_benefit), fill = "#69b3a2")+
geom_line(aes(y = a), col = rgb(0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1), size = 1)+
scale_y_continuous(name = "Net benefit",
sec.axis = sec_axis(~./10000+0.994, name = "Inflation"))+
theme_ipsum()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Year))+
  geom_col(aes(y = net_benefit), fill = "#69b3a2")+
  geom_line(aes(y = inflation_value*400), col = rgb(0.2, 0.6, 0.9, 1), size = 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Net benefit",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~{
                       a <- min(df$inflation_value)
                       b <- max(df$inflation_value)
                       ((((b-a) * (. - min(.)))/diff(range(.))) + a)
                     }))
```

[image]